# Deleting text between underscores

Tags: vim

Suppose I have this text segment embedded in a larger document

`var do_that_and_then_do_this`

I want to have a key-mapping such that if the cursor is over `that`, it gives

`var do_and_then_do_this`

And if the cursor is over `this`, it gives

`var do_that_and_then_do`

I tried doing the mapping

`nnoremap <leader>bla F_vt_x`

But it will only work for the first case (`that`). How can I modify it to work for the second case (`this`)?

Answer (score 4):

My [camelcasemotion plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1905) handles not just `CamelWords`, but also `underscore_words`. With it, your example would be `di,w` (using the custom`i,w` text object).

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a less simple answer, but you could create a macro and save it:

```
qadt_dF_q
```

Then to run it

```
@a
```

To save it in .vimrc

```
let @a='dt_dF_'
```

And that should do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

This is a little shorter than what you had, just use delete until instead of visual selection:

```
F_dt_
```